# Mapstruct: Mapping a dto in a dto to an entity in an entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, dto, mapstruct

Mapstruct is not using a mapper declared in the **"uses"** definition in the @Mapper Annotation
I expected the productCategory and productPrices to be mapped by the mappers: ProductPricesMapper.class, ProductCategoryMapper.class that are declared below but the generated code does not have them

**ProductMapper Interface**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE, uses = { ``
ProductPricesMapper.class, ProductCategoryMapper.class })`
public interface ProductMapper {`

    @Mapping(target = "lastUpdatedTime", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "creationTime", ignore = true)
    Product createEntityFromDto(ProductDto productDto);
    
}
```

**Generated Code:**

```
    @Autowired
    private ProductPricesMapper productPricesMapper;
    @Autowired
    private ProductCategoryMapper productCategoryMapper;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public Product createEntityFromDto(ProductDto productDto) {
        if ( productDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }
    
        Product product = new Product();
    
        product.setDescription( productDto.getDescription() );
        product.setId( productDto.getId() );
        product.setName( productDto.getName() );

        product.setProductCategory( productCategoryDtoToProductCategory( 
       productDto.getProductCategory() ) );
product.setProductPrices( productPricesDtoToProductPrices( productDto.getProductPrices() ) );

        return product;
    }
```

**Expected Generated Code**

```
@Component
public class ProductMapperImpl implements ProductMapper {

    @Autowired
    private ProductPricesMapper productPricesMapper;
    @Autowired
    private ProductCategoryMapper productCategoryMapper;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public Product createEntityFromDto(ProductDto productDto) {
        if ( productDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }
    
        Product product = new Product();
    
        product.setDescription( productDto.getDescription() );
        product.setId( productDto.getId() );
        product.setName( productDto.getName() );

       product.setProductCategory(productCategoryMapper.createEntityFromDto( productDto.getProductCategory() ));
product.setProductPrices( productPricesMapper.createEntityFromDto(productDto.getProductPrices()));
return product;

 }
```

**CODE FOR PRODUCT CATEGORY DTO TO PRODUCT CATEGORY**

```
 protected ProductCategory productCategoryDtoToProductCategory(ProductCategoryDto productCategoryDto) {
        if ( productCategoryDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ProductCategory productCategory = new ProductCategory();

        productCategory.setDescription( productCategoryDto.getDescription() );
        productCategory.setId( productCategoryDto.getId() );
        productCategory.setName( productCategoryDto.getName() );

        return productCategory;
    }
```

CODE FOR PRODUCT PRICES DTO TO PRODUCT PRICES

```
    protected ProductPrices productPricesDtoToProductPrices(ProductPricesDto productPricesDto) {
        if ( productPricesDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ProductPrices productPrices = new ProductPrices();

        productPrices.setBuyQuantityOffer( productPricesDto.getBuyQuantityOffer() );
        productPrices.setDiscount( productPricesDto.getDiscount() );
        productPrices.setGetQuantityOffer( productPricesDto.getGetQuantityOffer() );
        productPrices.setGetQuantityOfferProduct( productDtoToProduct( productPricesDto.getGetQuantityOfferProduct() ) );
        productPrices.setId( productPricesDto.getId() );
        productPrices.setSellingPrice( productPricesDto.getSellingPrice() );

        return productPrices;
    }
```

**ANOTHER SCENARIO**

when I have the following code in the ProductMapper but now it is vice versa the generated code is okay, so what is making the previous fail?

**CODE ADDED TO PRODUCT MAPPER**

```
ProductDto createDtoFromEntity(Product product);
```

**CORRECT GENERATED CODE**

```
@Override
    public ProductDto createDtoFromEntity(Product product) {
        if ( product == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ProductDto productDto = new ProductDto();

        productDto.setDescription( product.getDescription() );
        productDto.setId( product.getId() );
        productDto.setName( product.getName() );
        productDto.setProductCategory( productCategoryMapper.createDtoFromEntity( product.getProductCategory() ) );
        productDto.setProductPrices( productPricesMapper.createDtoFromEntity( product.getProductPrices() ) );

        return productDto;
    }
```

Comment: What is the code of productCategoryDtoToProductCategory ?

Comment: And as advice, you should not using the same DTOs for GUI rendering and for entity update/creation.

Comment: Appended in the post

Comment: If you want a mapper using a sub mapper. verify your method names are equal. And do you confirm that in your product mapper generated code, the sub mappers are autowired but still not used ?

Comment: or it's maybe because in your sub mapper you have different methods with the same signature, so your root mapper does not know which one to use

Comment: you can also try to @name(value="yourname") your submethod mapper and in your root mapper interface, specifying the mapping with @Mapping(target = "productCategory", source = "productCategory", qualifiedByName = "yourname")

Comment: They are autowired. Let me append some code to explain more

Comment: check the snippets appended to the post

Comment: any help on the above?

Comment: sorry i do not know why it isn't working like you would. Have you tried @name + qualifiedByName ?

Comment: At the end it's just some generated code, don't care too much about it (except if you implemented some rules into your child mapper that your parent have to use). And one time again. do not use the same DTOs for GUI and for entity update/creation.

Comment: Can you try removing all ignoring fileds like @Mapping(target = "lastUpdatedTime", ignore = true) on the parent  and child mappers. Just to check

Comment: Most likely your submappers don't provide the method signatures that MapStruct is looking for. What do they look like?